# AS/400 Using Replace

Tags: sql, database, db2

I tried to replace character at AS/400 Database using **REPLACE()** statement
but it's give me error like this

```
Coded Character Set Identifier 65535 not valid.
```

This is my sample code

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyField=REPLACE('Data/','/','-')
```

Is any other way to replace string or character at AS/400

Comment: From which tool on which operating-system are you submitting the SQL ?